# how can I set this score board

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

[image]

I add the tweet jump project high score source code in my project, and when I use this the output of my project is the screenshot

Comment: Do you mean tweejump? https://github.com/haqu/tweejump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use NSuserdefualt for storing and retrieving the data